# How can I link to a CMake target more concisely than specifying the absolute path to its output file?

Tags: cmake, build

I have a project with this structure:

- CMakeLists.txt
- LibraryProject
- - CMakeLists.txt
- - src
- UiProject
- - CMakeLists.txt
- - src

My top level CMakelists.txt looks like this:

```
project(Project)

add_subdirectory(LibraryProject)
add_subdirectory(UiProject)
```

The problem I have is that 'UiProject' depends on 'LibrayProject's' library, in it's CMakeLists.txt I added

```
target_link_libraries(UiProject <absolute path to library>)
```

And it works fine however I would like for it to work without providing an absolute path there (especially since output folder and library extension depends on the platform), is there a way to do it using CMake? Something like this:

```
... in top level CMakeLists.txt

project(Project)

output_path = add_subdirectory(LibraryProject)
add_subdirectory(UiProject, output_path)

... in UiProject's CMakeLists.txt

target_link_libraries(UiProject output_path)
```

Comment: You should be able to pass the name of the cmake library target to `target_link_libraries` instead of a path to the compiled library.

Comment: frankly, I'm surprised that you _didn't_ know that you could link to targets by name and _did_ know you could link by absolute path. I'd have expected it to be the other way around.

Comment: "`output_path = add_subdirectory(LibraryProject)`" there is no such syntax for CMake commands.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the dependency.

```
target_link_libraries(UiProject LibraryProject)
```

See the example library from CMake Modern introduction: https://gitlab.com/CLIUtils/modern-cmake/-/blob/master/examples/extended-project/apps/CMakeLists.txt#L4 .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to link to items using `target_link_libraries`. The simplest one- and the one you probably want- is to link by the name of the CMake target.

Assuming the target defined in your `LibraryProject` subdirectory is also called `LibraryProject`, you would use `target_link_libraries(UiProject LibraryProject)`.

If UiProject is a library, your should should also specify the visibility of the linkage (`PUBLIC` if things that want to use the interface of `UiProject` will definitely want to use the interface of `LibraryProject`).

All the ways you can choose from:

- A library target name
- A full path to a library file
- A plain library name
- A link flag
- A generator expression that evaluates to one of the above

See [the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) for full info.